# PHP PEAR Mail.php path problems

Tags: php, email, pear, include-path

I have a VPS running CentOS 6.5 with Directadmin. For a client I need the PEAR Mail function to work. I installed pear and pear Mail.
I followed the instructions on this page: http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.checking.php
to ensure the installation is correct. Which it is.

The problem is I still get a 'no such file or directory' error when I try to require my Mail.php file in a script.
I tried to embed system.php in the check_pear.php test from the manual, this is working fine and I get te Bool(true) message.

What I found is this:
My system.php file is located in /usr/local/lib/php while the Mail.php is located in /usr/share/pear/Mail.

I looked at the include path in phpinfo, this is pointing to /usr/local/lib/php. What is wrong? Do I need to add the /usr/share/pear path to include_path in php.ini?

Comment: Step 3 of the installation document tells you to include it in the php.ini so PHP can see the library. Try adding it to your includes and see if it starts working.

Answer (score 0):

`Mail.php` should be in the same directory as `System.php`. Somehow your setup is wrong.

How did you install the mail package?